# Sequence Diagram: Consuming Web Service from Android

Tags: uml, diagram, sequence-diagram

I am really consufed and i can't indetify the parts of an sequence diagram. I see ppls make simple sequence diagrams for some process, and other ppls make it extremly detailed.

Can you please help me to find an good (not the best) sequence diagram for the following actions: `Login` `Register`

Let me explain you:

- There is an Android application that Call web service in IIS Server
- When user ask for login, get back as response Full Name if success (i don't want to represent failure in diagram)
- In case of registration, user send data in Web Service. The Web service create an folder in HDD with user name. (It is file server, so we create user folder)

So, How i can represent the upper bullets in sequence diagram?

This is what i've done. I have no idea if it is right.

[Sequence Diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d78QR.png)

[Sequence Diagram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55MtK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no right or wrong here. The level of detail exposed in your sequence diagrams is a choice your team should make. The only 'wrong' way of doing it, is when you have multiple SDs for the same application, showing *different* levels of detail.

Who are going to use these sequence diagrams? Let's assume that they are developers who must implement it and, in the future, technical designers who must know how the current version of the product works, in order to design extensions to it.

In my opinion, the level of detail should be such, that the SDs give a clear overview of the flow, which provides enough information to know where to look in the source code (once it's finished) if you want to know more details.

You should sit together with the developers and your fellow designers and decide which lifelines (the official word for the participating objects) are valuable to show in the SDs. Once you know which lifelines to draw, I think it is the best strategy to include *all* messages interchanged by these lifelines.

If your audience consists of people like architects or product owners, then sit together with them. They may be interested only in a global view, in which case you should include less details.

Looking at your SDs, you seem to be in doubt whether to include 'Login Activity' as a lifeline. Personally, I'd say yes, so I'd prefer Sequence Diagram 2.

For more information about sequence diagrams for web applications, check [my paper](http://www.admiraalit.nl/admiraal/Technical-design-for-AngularJS-apps.pdf), chapter **Scenarios**.

Comment: It is a school-graduation project. In 2nd SD, what you think about `Server` ? Should i remove it and `User` -> `Web Service`?. Also, The result is the `Full Name` (or null. But at predconditions i have that credentials are valid), i should show the result ? becaus ei see many diagrams that have no result. PS: What about messages.

Comment: Yes, remove 'Server'. I suppose 'Login Activity' is the Android app? In that case, draw a message 'press Login button' from User to Login Activity and then a message 'Login' from Login Activity to Web Service. The text accompanying the return arrows should indicate the result, e.g. Full Name. Personally, I only show return arrows if there is an important result I want to mention.

Comment: After viewing many many sequence diagrams, i saw that almost all diagrams had no return messages. So i guess i will do the same. I will not return "Full Name".

Comment: First of all thank you all for participating in this discuss.

One last question. I have two classes `DbManager` and `FileManager` in the Web Service.

As sequence, i am thinking to use `WebService->DbManager->Database` and `WebService->FileManager->HDD`**instead of** `WebService->Database` and `WebService->HDD`.

As i mentioned, `DbManager` and `FileManager` are part (classes) of Web Service. Maby it is not "good practce" to follow the first approach. What do you think?

Ty.

Comment: It's absolutely fine to include DbManager and FileManager. Again, if you guess your readers are interested in this level of detail, it's fine, otherwise you'd leave these components out.

Answer (score 0):

All you want are method calls and return values, so basic SD things.

- Make a life line for the Android app and send a message from it to the IIS.
- Show the return value (full name) in the return message.
- You can send a message to a file service in the web server after authentication to create a folder. Eventually use an alt-fragment to show that it's doing that only on positive authentication.

So that's it. It's pretty much straight forward.

Comment: I am very skeptical about Server. Anyway! it is not big difference in diagram. I can add it later.

Comment: It is graduation project (Cloud Application). The Diagrams must not be extremly detailed (for programmers), also it must not be very generic. This is why i am very skeptical. I wan't to create diagrams that everyone can understand them (not only programmers) and will not be very generic.